# How do I use state data from BORIS with TraMineR?

Tags: r, dplyr, traminer

I am struggling to figure out how to convert the BORIS output into one of the state sequence analysis formats that I can analyze with TraMineR.

The BORIS outputs are basically tables that look like this:

```
                File    Time     Behavior Status
1  K8121319_feed3_01   0.000     Approach  START
2  K8121319_feed3_01 393.225     Approach   STOP
3  K8121319_feed3_01 393.226 Out-of-Frame  START
4  K8121319_feed3_01 426.003 Out-of-Frame   STOP
5  K8121319_feed3_01 442.006     Approach  START
6  K8121319_feed3_01 465.755     Approach   STOP
7  K8121319_feed3_01 465.756        Avoid  START
8  K8121319_feed3_01 513.255        Avoid   STOP
9  K8121319_feed3_01 513.256      Explore  START
10 K8121319_feed3_01 746.577      Explore   STOP
```

It seems like it would be possible to convert to the SPELL sequence format using dplyr, but I can't figure out how. Has anyone used these two softwares together?

The SPELL format would look like this:

```
                File Behavior     Start     Stop
1  K8121319_feed3_01 Approach      0.000    393.225
2  K8121319_feed3_01 OOF          393.226   426.003
3  K8121319_feed3_01 Approach     426.006   465.755
4  K8121319_feed3_01 Avoid        465.756   513.255
5  K8121319_feed3_01 Explore      513.256   746.577
```

I have been trying to use dplyr::spread to do this.

Edit: here is the result of dput(data1[1:20,])

```
structure(list(File = c("K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", 
"K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", 
"K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", 
"K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_01", "K8121319_feed3_02", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", 
"K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02", "K8121319_feed3_02"
), Time = c(0, 393.225, 393.226, 426.003, 442.006, 465.755, 465.756, 
513.255, 513.256, 746.577, 0, 29.85, 29.851, 66.6, 66.601, 292.646, 
292.647, 362.208, 362.209, 442.456), Behavior = c("Approach", 
"Approach", "Out-of-Frame", "Out-of-Frame", "Approach", "Approach", 
"Avoid", "Avoid", "Explore", "Explore", "Approach", "Approach", 
"Avoid", "Avoid", "Approach", "Approach", "Avoid", "Avoid", "Approach", 
"Approach"), Status = c("START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", 
"STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", 
"STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit: dput for part of df with repeated states

```
dput(data1[360:370,])

structure(list(File = c("K8121819_feed3_13", "K8121819_feed3_13", 
"K8121819_feed3_13", "K8121819_feed3_13", "K8121819_feed3_13", 
"K8121819_feed3_14", "K8121819_feed3_14", "K8121819_feed3_14", 
"K8121819_feed3_14", "K8121819_feed3_14", "K8121819_feed3_14"
), Time = c(700.311, 700.312, 720.311, 742.851, 754.339, 0, 32.124, 
32.125, 47.14, 47.141, 84.671), Behavior = c("Approach", "Avoid", 
"Avoid", "Avoid", "Avoid", "Avoid", "Avoid", "Explore", "Explore", 
"Approach", "Approach"), Status = c("STOP", "START", "STOP", 
"START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP"
)), row.names = 360:370, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: From the [user manual](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf) it seems that this package is meant to analyze categorical values over a discrete time series. Can you please clarify how you expect to transform continuous scale time data to discrete? Otherwise, I fear that this question is not on topic for Stack Overflow because it is not focused enough to be considered a **specific** programing question. It might be on topic for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) however.

Comment: TraMineR is used for sequence data. If you look at the formats in Table 4.2 of the user manual- it can be used with continuous time scales. See the SPELL format, which is similar. I will add to CV too. Thank you

Comment: yes, dplyr version is 1.0.0. Here are all the errors and warnings: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `START`.
x non-numeric argument to mathematical function
i Input `START` is `1L + as.integer(floor(START))`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

Comment: I confirm that TraMineR is for categorical sequences with discrete time scales. In Table 4.2 of the user manual, time is a discrete value. This is also true for the SPELL format where  `from` and `to` have to be discrete values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I question your statement that the SPELL format can be used with continuous data, because providing a double to `seqdef` results in an error that the beginning and end columns must be integer.

Hopefully this will get you started though:

**Edit**: Now to potentially fix duplicated Behavior states:

```
library(TraMineR)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
data.long <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(id = rleid(Behavior),
         Behavior = str_replace_all(Behavior,pattern = "-", replacement = "")) %>%
  group_by(File,id) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Time == min(Time) | Time == max(Time)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("File","Behavior", "id"),
              names_from = "Status",
              values_from = "Time") %>%
  mutate(START = 1L+as.integer(floor(START)),
         STOP = 1L+as.integer(floor(STOP))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

data.long
#                File   Behavior id START STOP
#1  K8121319_feed3_01   Approach  1     1  394
#2  K8121319_feed3_01 OutofFrame  2   394  427
#3  K8121319_feed3_01   Approach  3   443  466
#4  K8121319_feed3_01      Avoid  4   466  514
#5  K8121319_feed3_01    Explore  5   514  747
#6  K8121319_feed3_02   Approach  6     1   30
#7  K8121319_feed3_02      Avoid  7    30   67
#8  K8121319_feed3_02   Approach  8    67  293
#9  K8121319_feed3_02      Avoid  9   293  363
#10 K8121319_feed3_02   Approach 10   363  443
```

I removed the `-` because it was causing problems with `seqstatl`, and I added 1 because apparently the package authors thought 0 not allowed. I used `rleid` from the `data.table` package because it saved a lot of typing trying to use base R's `rle`.

Now we can use `seqdef`:

```
data.SPELL <- seqdef(data = data.long,
                     var = c("File", "START", "STOP", "Behavior"),
                     informat = "SPELL",
                     labels = seqstatl(data.long$Behavior),
                     states = seq_along(seqstatl(data.long$Behavior)),
                     process = FALSE)
data.SPELL
#K8121319_feed3_01 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3-3
#K8121319_feed3_02 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1
```

Comment: Just be aware of sequence length that the chosen time unit may imply, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19688976/1586731